# How can i report to University of Kentucky someone using their webpage to get seo rank?

Tags: seo

How can i report to University of Kentucky someone using their webpage to get seo rank?

This is the link .

http://www.uky.edu/seeblue/Social/index.html ( the did take it off after i speak with them about it )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact the university directly: http://www.uky.edu/UKHome/subpages/contact.html Ask to be patched through to whoever maintains their website. Or just ask for their email address. Let them know about the situation and leave it with them.

To answer your question; I don't think this is illegal. Just shady.

Comment: This seems to me to be a valid thing to say. I up-voted your answer because you speak to doing the right thing. Thank you for that.

Comment: thank you for link , i did speak with them and they did take it down